# Garbage collection for instances within singleton class

Tags: garbage-collection, singleton

I have a singleton class whose instance is alive throughout the lifespan of my application. From one of the singelton instance method I am creating instance of a Runnable thread and executing it. Will the runnable thread instance become a candidate for garbage collection after its execution or will it remain in heap forever since my singleton instance is always alive?

Eg: In the example below I create a new instance of MyRunnable class each time MySingleton.getInstance().runMyThread() is called. Will these MyRunnable instances be considered for garbage colletion once done with the run() method is completely executed and over?

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private MySingleton instance = null;

    private MySingleton() {}

    public static MySingleton getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MySingleton();
        }
    }  

    public void runMyThread()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable()); //MyRunnable implements Runnable
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general an object will be a candidate for garbage collection when
*it is no longer in scope* **and**
*nothing references it*.

In this scenario, assuming nothing is referencing the Thread object after it finishes execution it will become a candidate for garbage collection. In your example, your singleton instances does not *contain* any references to the Thread object - it calls runMyThread() which creates a new Thread object and starts it. The Thread object's scope is contained to the runMyThread() method.